# Android: does ByteStreams.toByteArray change content of source

Tags: arrays, bytestream

In my code I want the following functionality :

```
InputStream is = getInputStream()
byte[] buffer = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);
function1(buffer)
function2(is)
```

But what I observe is that if `ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);` is called then `function2` is not working properly. It works fine if I comment that particular line.
Also it works fine if I convert buffer back to stream; i.e. 
`function2( new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer))` works.

Can you please help me understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputStreams have a hidden state: the position in the stream. When anyone reads from an InputStream the position changes. This means you can't read a stream twice, you have to create a new stream.

`ByteStreams.toByteArray` has to read from the stream, so it changes the position.